# JFrame doesn't resize when JLabel gets longer

Tags: java, awt

I have the following, [code](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/6cedbbae235948d58b78299f58e5018e) which almost does what I want except it doesn't automatically stretch to the right, so the whole label can be seen. I've tried different constrains on it, but it doesn't change, setting the JFrame bigger works, but I would like it to resize depending on the label length, so it doesn't occupy more space on the screen than needed.
[The UI Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnuke.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run JFrame.pack() to resize the frame according to it's components.